# Use substitution cipher in python to encrypt and decrypt a .txt file and output to a new .txt file

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

I am able to open the rules file and create a dictionary to use for my encryption.  I have to also create a dictionary to use for decrypting text.  I assume it's basically the same function with minor changes.  The encrypt works fine, but I can't get the decrypt to work.  My second problem is that while I encrypted the file I took out all spaces and punctuation.  I can't figure out how to get those back in the output file once I run the program.  It just prints in a single column.  Lastly I have to output this to a .txt file.  I am able to create a .txt with a user assigned name, but can't get anything to print on the file.

Here is what I achieved so far.

```
#import clauses
import string


#function definitions



#encrypt dictionary
def createrulesdictencrypt(openFile):
    rulesencrypt1 = {}
    for line in openFile:
        rulessplit = string.split(string.strip(line))
        rulesencrypt1[rulessplit[0]] = rulessplit[1]
    return rulesencrypt1

#decrypt dictionary
def createrulesdictdecrypt(openFile):
    rulesdecrypt1 = {}
    for line in openFile:
        rulessplit = string.split(string.strip(line))
        rulesdecrypt1[rulessplit[1]] = rulessplit[0]
    return rulesdecrypt1

openFile = open('rules.txt', 'r')
rulesencrypt = createrulesdictencrypt(openFile)
rulesdecrypt = createrulesdictdecrypt(openFile)
#print rulesencrypt
#print rulesdecrypt




#function for encrypting file
def encryptfile(openFile2):
    for line in openFile2:
        for word in line.split():
            empty = ''
            for char in word:
                if char not in string.punctuation:
                    char=char.lower()
                    empty = empty+char 
                if len(empty) == 2:
                    print rulesencrypt[empty]
                    empty = ''
            if len(empty) == 1:
                print rulesencrypt[empty]



#function for decrypting file
def decryptfile(openFile2):
    for line in openFile2:
        for word in line.split():
            empty = ''
            for char in word:
                if char not in string.punctuation:
                    char=char.lower()
                    empty = empty+char 
                if len(empty) == 2:
                    print rulesdecrypt[empty]
                    empty = ''
            if len(empty) == 1:
                print rulesdecrypt[empty]


#main program

ende = raw_input("To encrypt a file, enter '0':\nTo decrypt a file, enter '1':")
filename = raw_input("Enter the name of the file to be processed:")
outfilename = raw_input("Enter the name of the file to save the result to:")
openFile2 = open(filename, 'r')
outputfile = open(outfilename, 'w')
fileencrypt = encryptfile(openFile2)
filedecrypt = decryptfile(openFile2)


if ende == "0":
    print encryptfile(fileencrypt)
if ende == "1":
    print decryptfile(filedecrypt)
```

This is what I am trying to encrypt

Sir Robin: "Oh, you liars!"

Minstrel: [singing] "Bravely taking to his feet, he beat a very brave
retreat. A brave retreat by brave Sir Robin."

Comment: The art of encryption is to show information in one way in another and decryption is to retrieve the information back in original way. So if at any point you lose some of the information you would never be able to recover back in original way, so my suggestion would be to first preserve all the information like punctuation and spaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're not actually writing your encrypted text to a file, instead you're just printing it to `sys.stdout`. Incidentally, `print` appends a \n to it's output by default.

You could rewrite your decrypt function as follows:

```
#function for decrypting file
def decryptfile(openFile2, outfile): # <- CHANGED to add outfile
    for line in openFile2:
        for word in line.split():
            empty = ''
            for char in word:
                if char not in string.punctuation:
                    char=char.lower()
                    empty = empty+char 
                if len(empty) == 2:
                    outfile.write(rulesdecrypt[empty]) # <- CHANGED to write to file
                    empty = ''
            if len(empty) == 1:
                outfile.write(rulesdecrypt[empty]) # <- CHANGED to write to file
```

You will then need to invoke the decryptfile function with a file as its second argument. A similar change could be made to the encryptfile function.

With respect to punctuation and whitespace, either encrypt it or just leave it in place. Once you've removed it, there really isn't a good way to replace it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help.  It still doesn't print anything to the file.  The reason I had it printing because once the user enters the name of the file they wanted encrypted or decrypted I have to print it in the shell as well as create a new text file.  I still have not been able to figure out how to print my out put in lines instead of one column.  Can you explain to me what I would need to do?

Comment: Don't use print, instead use sys.stdout.write() which will output only what you entered. In order to output to a file, you will need to invoke the file's write method. If you want to print to both a file and the console, you could write to both, or you could use a tee. A nice discussion is at : http://www.shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-tee.html